# Log4j mapping all loggers to a single logger

Tags: log4j

Our middleware team assignes logger names to each application and that is how they know where to direct our socket appenders to.

I would like to use the standard Logger.getLogger(Clazz.class) paradigm but that does not work with the above constraint.  Also we can't log library statements out to our socket appender which would come in handy a lot.

Is there a fairly painless way to map everything from all loggers to this middleware assigned logger?

I think our middleware group messed up in how the configured the enterprise logging system.  It looks like there is a setApplication property on the SocketAppender that should be used instead.    Regardless, this is what we have to deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to redirect your "regular" loggers' output to the "middleware logger" directly, i.e. without setting the middleware logger's appender on all the "regular" loggers, right?

If this is the case, try writing your own appender:

```
class MiddlewareRedirectingAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
     private Logger middlewareLogger = Logger.getLogger("your 'middleware' logger name");

     public void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
         // implement whatever filtering, etc. you want
         middlewareLogger.log(...);
     }
}
```

Attach this appender to your "regular" loggers, or just to the root logger (depending on how your "middleware" logger behaves).

Disclaimer: this is just a loose idea, I haven't tested it.